# Write a timer in shell script to trigger/run another prepared script

Tags: shell

Can anyone give me a hint how to write a timer shell script so that, e.g. once it's got to tomorrow midnight, it will run other scripts that are already prepared in the same directory. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What OS are you talking about? Windows? Linux?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you need a script to run at a specific time, could you leverage `cron`?

Comment: Or `at` -- http://man.cx/at

Comment: Run on Redhat. There is a SQL query generating reports written in Shell too that needs to be run on 11PM of this Sunday, I will not be around on computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the ability to use `cron` or `at`, you can do this with a script. The key commands are `sleep` to kill time and `date` to get the current time.  Something like (untested sh script):

```
 while sleep 600; do
      time=$(date +%H)
      if [ ${time} = '00' ]; then
           echo Now is the time
           break
      fi
 done
```

This technique allows running scripts periodically on systems where `cron` and `at` access is disabled.  The `break` is for one time use.  Adjust the sleep time to meet your needs.  `date` can return any number of variables that can be used to decide if the desired time has arrived.  For simple perodic runs the `if` statement can be removed.